# how to read a .txt file with BufferedInputStreamReader

Tags: java, utf-8, io, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

The problem, I think, is that the file is **in** the jar, which seems to make it a bit harder.

I don't understand how to instantiate an `InputStreamReader` when reading from a local file (inside the jar) as below:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Template {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName());
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    public Template() {
    }

    public String getTemplate() {
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public void load() {
//        try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.txt"))) {
        try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.txt")),"UTF-8")) {
            int data = input.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                buffer.append((char) data);
                data = input.read();

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

compile error (bad syntax):

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 14 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/src/net/bounceme/dur/client/Template.java:23: error: no suitable constructor found for BufferedInputStream(InputStreamReader,String)
    [javac]         try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.txt")),"UTF-8")) {
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]     constructor BufferedInputStream.BufferedInputStream(InputStream,int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual argument InputStreamReader cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion)
    [javac]     constructor BufferedInputStream.BufferedInputStream(InputStream) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] Note: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/src/net/bounceme/dur/client/gui/MailGUI.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/nbproject/build-impl.xml:924: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Mail/nbproject/build-impl.xml:264: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Mail$
```

for hovereel, the structure:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Mail$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Mail$ tree src/
src/
├── client.properties
├── logging.properties
├── META-INF
│   └── persistence.xml
├── net
│   └── bounceme
│       └── dur
│           └── client
│               ├── gui
│               │   ├── ApplicationDriver.java
│               │   ├── Goof.form
│               │   ├── Goof.java
│               │   ├── MailGUI.form
│               │   ├── MailGUI.java
│               │   └── TitleBuilder.java
│               ├── jdbc
│               │   ├── Agents.java
│               │   ├── Provinces.java
│               │   ├── State.java
│               │   ├── TitleException.java
│               │   ├── TitleFactory.java
│               │   └── Title.java
│               ├── MyProps.java
│               ├── NewJFrame.form
│               ├── NewJFrame.java
│               ├── SendTLS.java
│               └── Template.java
└── template.txt

7 directories, 21 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Mail$
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your jar file?

Comment: heh, not at the moment -- won't compile!  I will though.  it's in the "top" and this syntax can read the file, the path is correct.  it's in the default package with properties files.  I added a tree view of src to show path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wanted something like

```
try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.txt"))) {

}
```

Because there are only two constructors, per the [`BufferedInputStream` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html),

> ```
> BufferedInputStream(InputStream in)
>      Creates a BufferedInputStream and saves its argument, the input stream in, 
>      for later use.
> BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)
>      Creates a BufferedInputStream with the specified buffer size, and saves 
>      its argument, the input stream in, for later use.
> ```

And neither takes an `InputStreamReader`. You can of course wrap the above `BufferedInputStream` with one,

```
try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.txt"))) {
  InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: The first will only if your platform's native encoding is utf8. The first example wraps a `BufferedInputStream` around the `InputStream` that [`getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) returns.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see, you're trying to pass a Reader into a BufferedInputStream, and that's not allowed, since the BufferedInputStream only accepts an InputStream parameter, not a Reader. You're also not showing us the compilation error message. Instead, either go Elliott's route (1+) or pass the InputStream into a `BufferedReader` not a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: pardon, compilation error?  not sure what you mean or need.

Comment: Actually, it's in the post *compile error (bad syntax)*. May have been a five minute edit.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That's what confuses me. "bad syntax" doesn't mean much, is extremely non-descriptive and suggests that there's more error message that's missing.